# Create standalone Safari apps in macOS, like you can with Chrome?

Tags: macos, safari, big-sur

This thread explains how to turn a Chrome tab into a first-class Mac app that lives in the Dock:

> [How to make Web Apps appear as First-Class Mac Desktop Citizens](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291000/how-to-make-web-apps-appear-as-first-class-mac-desktop-citizens)

Looking for the same approach but with Safari instead of Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

Apple's official [Safari web apps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213583) adds this feature for macOS 14 Sonoma and Safari 17 in 2023:

1. In Safari, open the webpage that you want to use as a web app.
2. From the menu bar, choose **File > Add to Dock**.

   Or click the Share button  in the Safari toolbar, then choose **Add to Dock**.

This adds the website as a dedicated app icon in your Dock.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same question and found this: [Unite](https://www.bzgapps.com/unite)

Not affiliated with them in any way, created app and it uses Safari (Webkit framework).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.reddit.com/r/PWA/comments/ht2uc3/does_safari_in_macos_support_pwa/

It does not support PWAs on desktop yet

Comment: What is a PWA? and please provide an answer not just a link. An answer should standalone if the link is removed. (The link should stay in this case as you need to attribute who provided the information and to provide extra information)

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is an option with Safari. However, I've used an app called `Fluid` that can create websites into standalone apps. It is free, but there's extra minor features available for a small fee. Have a look at it here: https://fluidapp.com